# Need help with hardsurface modeling

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, bezier-curves

Please excuse me for this is my first time on stack exchange and also my second time asking for help on any type of forum, so please bear with me.

In the picture below (Sorry got this image a while back and cant remember the artist name) highlighted by the red circle, is how can I make that curve then dip? Sorry I dont really know how to explain this type of problem. Also how would I make the grip rounded at the same time while making the rest area rigid

In the pink circle, How would I make that edge overlay like the artist has done in their render?

Sorry if this is hard to understand as I am still fairly new to blender and 3d modeling its self but know the basics to some extent.
[image: reference image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your shape and I could get a rather satisfying result beginning with a boolean between a basic mesh and a torus, then join some vertices, etc... (everything mirrored fo course). Maybe it will help to show you my topology?

[image]

Comment: That looks like the solution to my problem but I am struggling on how you joined it so well?

Comment: it would be very tedious to describe step by step, but first I've joined my two meshes with a Boolean / Union mode, then I joined the vertices one by one, trying to keep quads as much as possible, then add some bevels to keep the angles sharp. Maybe follow some tutorials on hard surface object?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Just wish I could get my head around it all. You made it look so simple to do haha.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best topology possible though  ;)  you need to try a lot of these kind of projects and you will improve yourself. Also, if you like hardsurface, there's a nice addon: Speedflow. It wouldn't have been so useful for this object though.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two main techniques for having curved and straight angles on a mesh:

the first is a simple cube with the four top edges set with  an edge bevel weight higher than zero, and a Bevel modifier before a subsurf modifier.

[image]

The second hasn't a bevel modifier and uses instead some edge loop to "reinforce" the angles.

The more you are able to use the first method, the simpler and cleaner are the meshes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast and easy to follow answer as  this has answered alot of questions. But how would I do the curve on the left side of the hole shown in the red circle?