# Problem with creating a box on a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm making a box on my cylinder for my Luke Lightsaber modeling practice but by doing so I always create a pinch around the attaching points like
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm new to blender and I just finished blender guru's beginner tutorials and the anvil tutorials. It's always painful to perfect my mesh and vertices but I really want to learn how to solve these sort of problems so I'd be more than grateful if anyone like to give me a hint, instructions, or even just pointing out the problem (cause I can't even tell.) 
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer, and search infos about hard surfaces modeling: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128973/need-help-with-hardsurface-modeling/128975#128975

Comment: Sure! @joshsanfelici Thanks for giving me a direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It good that you try to keep the geometry as simple as possible. But in this case you need more geometry to avoid pinching.

In the inner (curved) edge loop I used the "Loop Cut and Slide" tool and selected Even (E) offset. You can Flip (F) from where it's even.

[image]

You can keep the other sections of the light sabre low in geometry. There are usually no reason to merge different parts seamlessly merged to each other.

[image]

You will find more tools and how you use them is up to you. I think that discover your way of solving problems is one of the more rewarding things with modelling. It's also quite tidies to do step-by-step instructions ;-) and at then end not that helpful.

Comment: Wow that looks amazing!
    
Another question: with so many vertices, how should I attach it with a low poly part without breaking the four-vertices rule?
    
Also, at the attaching part of your example, you made a curve line on the box before going back to straight lines. Is that essential to making the shape work? How did you do it?

Comment: Thank you! I just found out your new edit and I fully agree with you. It wouldn’t be “helpful” if it’s a step by step tutorial! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems hard to do with a very low poly mesh, I'm curious to know if there's a method to do it, but if you use a higher poly mesh, as shown by Jackdaw, you can sharp the angles with some bevels.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the screenshots! I also found it easier to make a hi-poly one, but didn’t know how to attach a hi-poly object with a low poly one due to the four vertices rule. Any idea how? BTW Is there anyway to avoid the triangle in the corner of your mesh? I was told not to do so (tho I didn’t really understand the reason why even tho blender guru sorta gave an explanation.)

Comment: I see that @Jackdaw edited his answer and both of you are very helpful! I’ll try my best. Thanks!

Comment: yes they are ways to avoid triangles but I don't think it worth it in that case